# How do I programmatically delete a node by internal url alias?

Tags: 8, nodes, path-aliases

How do I programmatically delete a node with a specific internal url alias?

Background: 
We are trying to delete this node so that it can be replaced during an update hook.

Comment: Did you want to delete a node by node/nid or the actual alias that is stored inside the url_alias table? Like articles/this-is-a-title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging around through the available services and core classes, I have determined you need to get the *nid* through the *path.alias_manager*.  Additionally you need to wrap everything in a couple of conditions or you will throw errors if the path does not exist.  (eg. if you are trying to roll this change out to a fleet of sites that might or might not have this path already)

Below is my example code:

```
  // Check the path is valid before proceeding.
  $pathIsValid = \Drupal::pathValidator()->isValid('/blog');

  if ($pathIsValid) {
      $alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getPathByAlias('/blog');
      $params = Url::fromUri("internal:" . $alias)->getRouteParameters();
      // Get nid.
      $nid = $params[$entity_type];
      $node = Node::load($nid);

      // Check if node exists with the given nid.
      if ($node) {
      $node->delete();
    }
```

Comment: I think you'll find that the lines starting "$nodeObj = " and "$node =" are essentially doing the same thing. $params[$entity_type] will be the node ID. So you can simplify the code a bit

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong not true.  $nodeObj is what is used to get the NID from the aliases in the routing table.   We can then delete the node once we have the NID.

Comment: You have the nid already. Print $params[$entity_type] and see what you get. And \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type)->load() is equivalent to Node::load() when entity_type is node.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong. Thanks for following up, you are correct :)   Updating the answer above to reflect your recommendations.   Cheers!